# Solving a system of equations with numerical approximation

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

Let `a, b, c` be vectors obtained with the function `N` and `x, y` be scalars. I have the equation:

```
Solve[a == x b + y c, {x, y}]
```

Since I have used `N`, I get an empty solution, but I know that a solution exists.

Is there any way to find some sort of approximation such that the equation is satisfied?

I don't know how to do it. but maybe a solution with an interval for `x` and `y`?

$x \pm c1$ and $y \pm c2$

Comment: `xb` is not the same thing as `x*b` or `x b`.

Comment: Take a loot at [`LeastSquares`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear equation, and you are probably looking for a least squares solution. So,

```
LeastSquares[Transpose[{b, c}], a]
```

should work.

To problem here is that there are either no or infinitely many (a line of) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Solve`, you are asking Mathematica to **solve** for $x$ **and** $y$, which is not possible, as the system of equations is under defined. You can either solve for one of the unkowns

```
Solve[a == x b + y c, {x}]
```

[image]

or reduce the equations into simpler conditions

```
Reduce[a == x b + y c, {x, y}]
```

[image]